# Attaching a existing object into a new one on SQLAlchemy and Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a new object and attach an already existing one on it, but I'm getting an error " sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '' is already attached to session '4' (this is '5') "

Here's are my models:

```
class User(Base):
__tablename__ = 'users'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
username = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
password = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
name = Column(String(300), nullable=False)
conversation = relationship('Conversation',backref ='users',lazy='subquery')


class Response(Base):
__tablename__ = 'responses'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
response = Column(String(500), nullable=False)
intent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('intents.id'))


class Pattern(Base):
__tablename__ = 'patterns'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
pattern = Column(String(300), nullable=False)
intent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('intents.id'))


class Conversation(Base):
__tablename__ = 'conversations'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
question = Column(String(500), nullable=False)
classify = Column(Float(5))
date = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now())

response_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('responses.id'))
response = relationship('Response', lazy='subquery')

intent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('intents.id'))
intent = relationship('Intent', lazy='subquery')

user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
user = relationship('User', lazy='subquery')


class Intent(Base):
__tablename__ = 'intents'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True,autoincrement=True)
tag = Column(String(50), nullable = False)
context_filter = Column(String(50), nullable = True)
context_set = Column(String(50), nullable = True)
patterns = relationship('Pattern',backref ='intents', lazy='subquery')
responses = relationship('Response',backref='intents', lazy='subquery')
```

What i'm trying to is to get a intent from the database and put into a new conversation Object, here's what i'm trying to do, but it is not working:

```
cv = Conversation()
cv.user = getSingleUser(question['idUser'])

cv.question = question['question']
cv.classify = classify[1]

responseDict = chatBotResponse(question['question'])
cv.response = getSingleResponse(responseDict['id'])

intent = getIntentByName(classify[0])
cv.intent = intent

insertEdit(cv)
```

//Database Class

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def getSingleUser(id):
    session = DBSession()
    user = session.query(User).filter_by(id=id).first()
    session.close()
    return user

def getSingleResponse(id):
    session = DBSession()
    response = session.query(Response).filter_by(id=id).first()
    session.close()
    return response

def getIntentByName(name):
    session = DBSession()
    intent = session.query(Intent).filter_by(tag=name).first()
    return intent

def insertEdit(obj):
    session = DBSession()
    session.add(obj)
    session.commit()
    session.close()
```

But all I'm getting is

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object 'Intent at 0x226e9ffe5f8' is already attached to session '4' (this is '5')

Can someone point me out what I'm doing wrong, and how is the best way to do what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to create 4 different sessions or could you have a single session? The error just states that the `Intent` object was already attached to session 4, but the current session is 5.

Comment: @kstullich I could use only one, but my database functions are in another file, and I don't know how I could do such thing in just one session... Should I declare "session = DBSession()"  just one time on the Database class?

Comment: @JoãoVitorRomerodaCruz there is a pretty thorough coverage of session use basics here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#session-frequently-asked-questions. Worth a read if you haven't already.